# How to get what is sent in a XmlHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, url, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

Hello I am having trouble sending XmlHttpRequests, I have to send post and get requests to a server and i need to use formdata, however one of the platforms i am developing for doesn't have formdata, so my question is, is there a way to see the url with the formdata attached, that is being sent from a platform that works(google chrome or firefox), and copy it so i can create a work around?

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have some form of Developer Tools (often tied to the F12 key) which include a Network tab that will display information about each request made from a page.

[image: Firefox developer tools]

Additionally, the HTML 5 specification [describes how to convert an HTML form into a string of form data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-0). That should save you from having to reverse engineer the process from an example.

Comment: i know this but when i look at it in the developer tools, it shows me the break down and not what i am looking for, as in the full url that is sent

Comment: @GavClarke — It will show you the full URL. (Of course, if the request is a POST request then the data won't be in the URL, but it should still have an option to show you the raw request body)

Comment: Do you mean the request payload? if so is there a way to send the request payload as part of the url, or am i dreaming?

Comment: Some server systems allow you to switch between the query string and the request body freely (and some also allow you to switch between POST and GET requests freely). You'd have to change the code making the request to do it. Doing so is generally a terrible idea though.

Comment: would there be another way to send the data that is similar to a formdata object but not a formdata object if you understand me?

Comment: A FormData object is just a way of collecting a bunch of data together and formatting it into a string. You can do that by hand. The algorithm is linked in the answer.